# Duplicate Insertion to the database in php

Tags: php, sql

I had tried to make an attendance system using PHP and SQL. The Insertion part is working well but I want to check the database for the attendance entry whether it is already stored or not. If stored then echo already stored else insert the time and date to the database table. But the Code is not working.

Every time I click the Intime button, on each button click the time and date stored in the database.

Here is the code:

```
 $eid=$_SESSION['emplogin'];

 $sql = "SELECT * from  tbl_employees where EmailId=:eid";
 $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
 $query->bindParam(':eid',$eid,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$id = $result->EmpId;

if(isset($_POST['intime']))
{
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
     $sql    = "SELECT date FROM tbl_in_time_attendance where EmpId = :eid ORDER BY tbl_in_time_attendance.date DESC LIMIT 1";
     $query  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
     $query->bindParam(':eid',$eid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $query->execute();
     $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     $dbdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->date));
     $date   = date('Y-m-d');

     if($dbdate != $date)
     {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_in_time_attendance (EmpId)VALUES (:id)";
         $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
         $query->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $query->execute();
     } 
     else
     {
         $message= "In Time Of today is already stored";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
     }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should only check the data not the time. As time will change every time you run your code. ```$data``` and ```$dbdate``` will never become equals

Comment: I use $date = date(Y-m-d) and NOW() for storing current time. But the database is not checked each time I click the intime button

Comment: We don't know the content of `$dbdate` in your code so we can't really help you. You need to do some debugging and check this is what you're expecting. Didn't you think of doing that already? Presumably this value is not a date, or is not _only_ a date. If it has time in it as well, then it will never match with a string containing just a date. Also remember you're matching strings here, not datetime objects

Comment: @ADyson Please now check the updated source code..  I want to make an attendance system where a user clicks the button and the time and date will be stored in the database

Comment: @AtulAman and does this update resolve your problem, or not? Is there new problem? Please clarify the situation. Did you debug the values being used in the `if` statement, as I suggested? Changing the code is no use if you don't test it fully. Echo those values out to see if they contain what you expected them to. Presumably, they don't. Once you see what's in there it'll give you a better idea of what to do to make them work as intended.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried everything but I am not able to find where the mistake is.

Comment: I'll repeat: Did you debug the values being used in the `if` statement, as I suggested? What values did you get (in a case where the problem occurs)? If you want some help, please do that, and show us the values you get back for `$date` and `$dbdate`. If they don't match when you expected them to, you'll know that's the beginning of finding the mistake. This is just simple debugging work. I don't know what you've tried and what you haven't, whether you did it correctly, what results you got etc etc. Please be clear and specific, and test one thing at a time, methodically and logically.

Comment: @ADyson  Thanks for your help. The code executes successfully

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing database datetime with current datetime and its never going to be same, So you have to compare dates

Try below code and it should work as you expected,

```
if(isset($_POST['intime']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $sql    = "SELECT date FROM tbl_in_time_attendance where EmpId = :eid ORDER BY tbl_in_time_attendance.date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':eid',$eid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->date));
    $date   = date('Y-m-d');

    if($dbdate != $date) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_in_time_attendance (EmpId)VALUES (:id)";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
    } else {
        $message= "In Time Of today is already stored";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: In SQL i have set the datatype as date  not the datetime

Comment: Then just change your $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); to $date = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: do a var_dump of both database and current date variables

Comment: I have to store current date and time in the database that's why I use date('Y-m-d H:i:s').  In  database I set "time" as datatype for current time and "date" for current date

Comment: @AtulAman Your question is unclear now! What is your datatype in database to store login time?

Comment: "time" is the datatype for storing the current time in the database

Comment: I want to insert the intime and date in the database whenever anyone clicks the button. I want to put a condition to check whether the intime of current date is already stored or not in the database. If already stored then it should alert the user that the time is already stored else insert the time and date to the database

Comment: @AtulAman Change your datatype of "date" as follows TIMESTAMP and set "default" as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP also "on update" as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. So that you don't have to feed time and date we you insert new record. See updated source code

Comment: then I have to delete the time column??

Comment: Yes, because there is no need to have two columns to store date and time.

Comment: I changed the code but the condition is not checked... see the updated source code

Comment: You need to do some debugging to find what is wrong, check the table whether the new record is inserted as required with timestamp.

Comment: Sir, If you provide ur email I can send the code, I tried everything but I am not able to understand what part is wrong in the code.